# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row Update SQL Query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to update column where find duplicate CNICNO and update column. But I am getting following error

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

When I query to find duplicate CNICNO records against HOFID then show 5 duplicate records

**Duplicate Records Query:**

```
SELECT hofid
         FROM hof 
        WHERE cnicno IN (SELECT cnic_no FROM we_group_hof_k)
```

**Records:**

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltC1m.png
```

In table "WE_GROUP_HOF_K" column "GROUP_ID" null records. I want "HOFID" records update with "GROUP_ID" column.

**SQL QUERY:**

```
UPDATE we_group_hof_k
SET group_id = (SELECT cnicno
         FROM hof 
        WHERE cnicno IN (SELECT cnic_no FROM we_group_hof_k));
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify the "update column with duplicates" requirement - what rows do you want to update if you've got duplicates, and to what value do you want to set the group_id? (please add example input and expected output to your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm wrong, shouldn't `UPDATE` actually look like this?

```
UPDATE we_group_hof_k w
   SET w.GROUP_ID =
          (SELECT h.cnicno
             FROM hof h
            WHERE h.cnicno = w.cnic_no);
```

Instead of `IN`, join appropriate columns form the table to be updated (`we_group_hof_k`) with the data source table (`hof`).

Answer (score 1):

The error message pretty much nails the problem - your subquery:

```
SELECT cnicno
         FROM hof 
        WHERE cnicno IN (SELECT cnic_no FROM we_group_hof_k)
```

returns multiple rows. But UPDATE needs a single value, so you have to ensure that your subquery returns only a single row. You need to ensure that your subquery never returns multiple rows (you can use an aggregate function like `MAX()` but you have to ensure that fits your business needs).

Comment: I want only update column with duplicate records. With simple query 5 records are duplicate